# How to uppercase a cell range even if user type or paste lowercase with no warning in Google Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, warnings, uppercase, automatic-updates

I've made a simple table in a one of many sheets in a google sheet file and I would like a cell range of a sheet to alway appear upper case no mater what user input without any warning.

Currently I found and used the script below in Apps Script and it works on all sheets and only on input texts, not pasted texts, but I would like to upper case a cell range on a sheet only.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if (Object.prototype.toString.call(e.range.getValue()) !== "[object Date]" ) {    
    if (!e.range.getFormula()) {
      e.range.setValue(e.value.toUpperCase());
    }
  }
}
```

Can someone help please? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

#### Something like this

```
function lfunko() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("SheetName");
  const rgA1 ="Whatever"
  let vo = sh.getRange(rgA1).getDisplayValues().map(r => {
    let row = []
    r.forEach(e => row.push(e.toUpperCase()));
    return row
  })
  sh.getRange(rgA1).setValues(vo);
}
```

Comment: Thanks you mean like this: 

function lfunko() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Trade History");
  const rgA1 ="B2:C1000"
  let vo = sh.getRange(rgA1).getDisplayValues().map(r => {
    let row = []
    r.forEach(e => row.push(e.toUpperCase()));
    return row
  })
  sh.getRange(rgA1).setValues(vo);
}

Comment: Thanks, it doesn't work. I also did it like this and not working: 
function lfunko() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Trade History");
  const rgA1 ="C4"
  let vo = sh.getRange(rgA1).getDisplayValues().map(r => {
    let row = []
    r.forEach(e => row.push(e.toUpperCase()));
    return row
  })
  sh.getRange(rgA1).setValues(vo);
}

Answer (score 1):

### Try:

```
function onEdit(e) {

  if (e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === `Trade History`) {

    if ((e.range.columnStart >= 2 && e.range.columnEnd <= 3) && (e.range.rowStart >= 2 && e.range.rowEnd <= 1000)) {

      const values = e.range.getDisplayValues().map(i => i.map(item => String(item).toUpperCase()))

      e.range.setValues(values)

    }

  }

}
```

This works by first checking the event happened on the correct sheet by name, then checks the changed cells occurred within a specified range (from your comment, the current range is B2:C1000).

If the changed cells meet these conditions, the values from the range are then converted to UpperCase and set.

Comment: Thanks, it didn't work when I used it like this, what am I doing wrong?

function onEdit(e) {

  const targetSheet = `Trade History`
  const targetCell = `B2:C1000`

  if (e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === targetSheet && e.range.getA1Notation() === targetCell) {

    e.range.setValue(String(e.value).toUpperCase())

  }

}

Comment: Alternatively I did this and it didn't work, again what am I doing wrong?

function onEdit(e) {

  if (e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === `Trade History` && e.range.getA1Notation() === `B2:C1000`) {

    e.range.setValue(String(e.value).toUpperCase())

  }

}

Comment: That's because your "cell" is a range of about 200 cells. I see you updated your post haha.

Comment: Thanks, yes I did haha. This worked only on one CELL as soon as I add a range it doesn't work even A1:A2

Comment: Updated and tested.

Comment: Many Thanks , it didn't work but when I looked closer I realised the line that starts with ".map(i =>" has more than one tab spacing, so I deleted the excessive tabs and all works. You're a genius Newaza!  <br> please update your work so that everyone can benefit from it ;)

Comment: Spacing shouldn't be an issue, that's odd. Would you mind slapping this answer as solved? Best wishes, let me know if you need any other help!