# How to uppercase a cell range, sheet except one single word

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, uppercase

I found here,

[How to uppercase a cell range even if user type or paste lowercase with no warning in Google Sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72243160/how-to-uppercase-a-cell-range-even-if-user-type-or-paste-lowercase-with-no-warni)

the following code which solved my problem that, with `onEdit` trigger to uppercase words only in a specific range & sheet, not within the entire spreadsheet:

```
function onEdit(e) {

  if (e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === `Trade History`) {

    if ((e.range.columnStart >= 2 && e.range.columnEnd <= 3) && (e.range.rowStart >= 2 && e.range.rowEnd <= 1000)) {

      const values = e.range.getDisplayValues().map(i => i.map(item => String(item).toUpperCase()))

      e.range.setValues(values)

    }

  }

}
```

I need now one single word in that range not to be uppercased, like "Hello" - this word I need to be ignored by the `onEdit` uppercase code, every time I write that specific word in that range.

I have really no idea how to solve my problem.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. You might find helpful spend some time learning the pretty basics of JavaScript, more specifically how to handle strings including the pretty basics of regular expressions. This will help you a lot to make more effective searches and to make your questions better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  e.source.toast("Entry");
  if (e.range.getSheet().getName() == `Sheet0`) {
    const wd = "Hello";
    if (e.range.columnStart > 1 && e.range.columnEnd < 4 && e.range.rowStart > 1 && e.range.rowEnd < 1001) {
      e.source.toast("Gate1")
      const values = e.range.getDisplayValues().map(r => r.map(c => {
        let idx = c.toString().indexOf(wd);
        Logger.log(idx);
        if (~idx) {
          let t = c.toString().split(wd);
          Logger.log(JSON.stringify(t));
          return t[0].toString().toUpperCase() + wd + t[1].toString().toUpperCase();
        } else {
          return c.toString().toUpperCase();
        }
      }))
      e.range.setValues(values)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Also, this string sayHellobrother is uppecased like this: SAYHelloBROTHER

Comment: I don't understand all of you last comment could you be a little more precise in your description on the problems.

Comment: I don t know how to explain better, I've recorded my screen for you to see how it works. I put it on youtube and you can see the video here: https://youtu.be/8J2zIdrRnZ4. In my video you can see there the Cooper code and range, and NEWAZA code and range. When I write something in Cooper range, the word simply dissapear... When I write in NEWAZA range, the word is uppercased and not dissapear. I need in Cooper range to uppercase all words I write, like in NEWAZA range, except one word: Hello. And I want the words not to dissapear after I write it. I hope now you understand what I need.

Comment: ... and in 1 cell I only write 1 word, I never use that range of cells to write more than 1 single word in every cell of that range.

Comment: ... The code should be related to cellcontent, like if { cell.Content == "Hello" then... not uppercase... else uppercase...} I think it should be something like that.

Comment: I think there's a couple of things going on.  I think you may have multiple onEdits which is causing problems and I made a change to return the entire string in uppercase if the word is not found

Comment: Now the code is working as intended.